# Can a list be used as a key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I read that list cannot be used as a key in a dictionary in python but I tried and its working fine. What am I missing? This is what I tried.

```
a={'hello':2,'[2,4,3]':'hi'}
print(a)
```

gives:

```
{'hello': 2, '[2,4,3]': 'hi'}
```

Comment: `'[2,4,3]'` is a string, not a list.

Comment: If for whatever reason you want to have collection type as a key, you can use immutable type as `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

`'[2,4,3]'` is a string. If you take away the quotation marks, then it's a list. And if you try to assign it as a key you'd get:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`